# value of fraction

Tags: complex-analysis

Can we find out the value of

$$\frac{1+i}{1-i}$$

I have tried to solve it by multiplying $(1+i)$ to both sides and in the end see that the result is still $i$. Am I correct,or is there a different solution?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: @iostreamoo7,thanks.

Comment: And thanks to the person who retagged it.

Comment: Note that $i\times(1-i)=i+1$

Comment: @rahul Your welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You divide by complex numbers, by multiplying by its conjugate, that is, replace in the divisor $+i$ by $-i$.  The product of $(a+ib) \cdot (a-ib) = a^2+b^2$, a real.
$$
\frac{1+i}{1-i}\frac{1+i}{1+i}=\frac{2i}2=i.
$$

Comment: Stumbled at the last hurdle! It is i.

Comment: where is $\dfrac{2}{2i}$?

Answer (score 0):

As OP has answer I want to write a basic thing to solve this type of problems of complex number.Whenever you saw terms containing $i$ in denominator,try to get rid of them either using the rationalizing process(used in this question) or by partial fraction (using this method is based on question type).some useful values of $i$:

$i^2=-1; \,i^3=-i;\,i^4=1;\,\dfrac{1}{i}=-i$

Any power greater than 4 can reduced to remainder of that power divides by 4.